# Moving $d$ terms inside a double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

I was dealing with an integral expression like that:
$$\int zf(z)dz$$

In this term it is known that $f(z)=\int g(x,z) dx$. So I can replace $f(z)$ in the first term  like that:

$$\int z(\int g(x,z)dx)dz$$

$g(x,z)$ is a well behaving, continuous function. Now it becomes very convenient for me to rearrange this like $\int \int zg(x,z)dz dx$ and solve this as iterated integrals, first the term $\int g(x,z)dz$ and then the outer integral over $x$.

But I am not sure whether this rearranging thing is mathematically correct. I know that $dx$ and $dz$ can be switched if we have continuous functions from my calculus courses, but here, we introduce $\int g(x,z)dx$ in parentheses and take it out from parentheses as we are multiplying it with $zdz$ and then $dx$ goes out of the integral it was belonging to first, $dz$ comes into its place and we integrate $g(x,z)$ according to $z$ then. I cannot convince myself that all this process is mathematically correct at all. Is this really correct and if it is, how it can be shown that it is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If $g$ is sufficiently well-behaved, you get $$\int z\int g(x,z)\,dx\,dz = \int \left(\int zg(x,z)\,dz\right)\,dx.$$ You must have the $z$ factor inside the integral with respect to $dz$.

Comment: That was my mistake, I corrected it, took $z$ inside the integral. But still my questions remain; can I multiply a term inside parenthesis with $dz$ as if it were a number to took it outside of the parenthesis? How is this justified and what is the well-behaving criterion for switching $dz$ and $dx$; as far as I remember, it was Fubini's theorem which tells that if $g$ is continuous in the area of integration, we can switch $d$ terms and apply iterated integrals.

Comment: The parentheses are irrelevant here. For the inner integral, $z$ is a constant, so $z \int g(x,z)\,dx = \int zg(x,z)\,dx$. Then the question is whether you can change the order of integration. That depends on $zg(x,z)$, and the domains of integration. If the integrals are both over compact intervals ($[a,b]$), then continuity of $g$ is enough. If you integrate over $\mathbb{R}$, continuity by itself is not enough. Generally, the Fubini and Tonelli theorems are pertinent.

Comment: If we integrate over $\mathbb{R}$, why continuity is not enough? What will be enough in that case? I am asking this because I am mostly dealing probability density functions which are integrated over all real numbers. Unfortunately I lack any measure theoretic background so I am sorry if this question is too trivial.

Comment: If you integrate over $\mathbb{R}$, positive and negative values can cancel out in one order of integration but not in the other. Basically, what you need is that $\iint \lvert zg(x,z)\rvert\,dx\,dz < \infty$ (plus measurability, but for continuous functions that is given). If you integrate over compact intervals, a continuous function is bounded, and the measure of the domain of integration is finite, so the integral of the absolute value is finite. If you integrate over $\mathbb{R}$, the measure is infinite, so you also need growth restrictions. When you are dealing with probability density

Comment: functions, most of the time you can switch the order of integrations. If $g(x,z) \geqslant 0$, for example, then you can switch the order of integration for the two parts $$\int_{z \geqslant 0} \int zg(x,z)\,dx\,dz\text{ and } \int_{z < 0}\int zg(x,z)\,dx\,dz,$$ since the integrand has constant sign for both integrals. If at least one of the two integrals is finite, you can switch the order of integration even if the other is infinite (then the total integral is a well-defined $\pm\infty$). If both integrals are finite, the absolute value is integrable and you can switch anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give an example about how positive and negative values cannot cancel out each other when we integrate over $\mathbb{R}$? And given the integral over infinity, does the growth restriction $\int\int |g(x,z)| dx dz < \infty$ provide that negative and positive values cancel each other out?

Comment: $$h(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 &, \max\{0,x\} \leqslant y \leqslant x+1\\ -1 &, \max \{0,x-1\} \leqslant y < x\\ 0 &, \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$ Then $\int \left(\int h(x,y)\,dx\right)\,dy = 0$, but $\int \left(\int h(x,y)\,dy\right)\,dx > 0$. The condition $\iint \lvert zg(x,z)\rvert\,dx\,dz < \infty$ guarantees that that can't happen.

Answer (score 1):

You may find my answer irrelevant, but I hope it will somehow help you.

May I assume $$F(x,z)=\int zf_x(z)dz=\int z(\int g(x,z)dx)dz$$ and $$G(x,z)=\int (\int zg(x,z)dz)dx$$. (which are 2-variable functions)

Then we have:$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$$ or $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial z}(F-G)=0$$ which means $$F-G=f_1(x)+f_2(z)$$ Does this condition help you in any way?